# how to break chaining selectors in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have some doubts in break the `jquery chaining selectors`.

For example, Consider this is my sample code,

```
<script>
      $("#button1, #button2, #button3, #button4, #button5, #button6 ").show();
</script>
```

I want to change like this format,

```
<script>
      $("#button1, #button2, 
         #button3, #button4, 
         #button5, #button6 ").show();
</script>
```

Please help. Thanks in advance..

Comment: Better question, why not `$('[id^="button"]')`, or a class ?

Comment: I just write my sample code for understanding. it's not a real one.

Comment: The simple answer is; strings can not be split up over multiple lines in javascript. You can concatenate strings like in the answers below, but that would be seperate strings added together, as you generally can't split them over multiple lines, and that goes for any string, not just selectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We pass a `string` to jQuery selector function. The difference in above two is that in first string is well formed and in second you have to concatenate it otherwise you will get `error`. you can concatenate it like this,

```
$("#button1, #button2, \
     #button3, #button4, \
     #button5, #button6 ").show();
```

Or

```
  $("#button1, #button2,"+ 
         "#button3, #button4, "+
         "#button5, #button6 ").show();
```

You can assign a common `class` to all buttons and use [**class selector**](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) to show hide them.

```
$('.button-class').show();
```

You can use [**attribute selector using wild card starts with**](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) if you have pattern for ids as given in question.

```
$('[id^=button]).show();
```

Comment: Without concatenation is it possible to do that.

Comment: Its not IMO as you stated but why dont you put it on single line?

Comment: I have add few of more possible solutions for selector.

Comment: ok. I understood, this is not my real code. Anyway thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate using `+`

```
$("#button1, #button2,"+ 
         "#button3, #button4, "+
         "#button5, #button6 ").show();
```

or use `\`

```
$("#button1, #button2, \
   #button3, #button4, \
   #button5, #button6 ").show();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either concatenate the strings of use the `\` character to wrap the string to the next line.

```
$("#button1, #button2," +
  "#button3, #button4," +
  "#button5, #button6 ").show();
```

Or

```
$("#button1, #button2, \
   #button3, #button4, \
   #button5, #button6 ").show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try some thing like this

```
$("#button1, " + 
    "#button2, " +
    "#button3").click(function(){
    alert("asdas");
});
```